# Changing Cronjob path

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to get a cronjob to run a basic Python script as a proof-of-concept exercise. The Python script goes as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
with open('realfile','a+') as f:
     f.write('testwrite\n')
```

My script is located (along with the 'realfile' file) in a 'Documents' directory that is one below my home directory (i.e. $HOME/Documents).

My crontab is as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * /$HOME/Documents/crontest.py
```

For some reason the crontab does not execute the script every minute as it should. The script works fine, as I manually ran it from command line (using ./crontest.py). In addition, the crontab worked completely fine when the script was located in the home directory and the crontab was simply:

```
*/1 * * * * /$HOME/crontest.py
```

I have checked the location of 'crontest.py' using 'locate crontest.py' and I got the following two locations:
/home/meric/crontest.py 
/usr/bin/crontest.py

I tried setting both of these paths in my crontab, and still the job won't run.

What could be the problem? Thanks for the help!

Comment: use fully expanded, absolute paths in both the crontab entry and your script and see if that helps.

Comment: also, if your email setup (nullmailer?) is configured correctly, you should be sent an email with details on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, cron jobs' working directory is the home of the user they execute as. Thus if you have both `crontest.py` and `realfile` in your `Documents` subdir, `crontest.py` should execute, and then fail when it can't find `realfile` in your home. Do recheck paths as Owen said; also, you can use this to run in an arbitrary working directory:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/meric/Documents && ./crontest.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not in the directory:

```
/$HOME/Documents/crontest.py
```

You say at the bottom that it's in:

```
/home/meric/crontest.py /usr/bin/crontest.py
```

Why not copy it to:

```
$HOME/Documents/crontest.py
```

and try again.

Comment: The thing is, my script is actually located in that directory. I'm not sure why 'locate crontest.py' gives those two paths, when 'crontest.py' is in fact located in $HOME/Documents/crontest.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the absolute path on the python code. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
with open((os.getenv('HOME') + '/Documents/' +'realfile'),'a+') as f:
   f.write('testwrite\n')
```

And edit the cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * $HOME/Documents/crontest.py
```

because `$HOME` variable already contain the `/`